Why can't I make a single method to add a single user or a list of users in my POST request?
I'm learning a little about Rest Controller in Spring Boot, and i'm really a beginner, and i'm doing some tests here and this question came to me. This first option returned error 500. While researching I saw that trying to map directly to Object can cause problems because Spring Boot cannot infer the exact type during JSON deserialization. I would just like to understand a little more
// Save a list of users or a single user
    @PostMapping()
    public void save(@RequestBody Object request){
        if(request instanceof List<?>){
            List<?> users = (List<?>) request;
            // It will iterate through each object in the list to add the user
            for(Object obj : users){
                repository.save((User) obj);
            }
        }
        else if (request instanceof Usuario){
            repository.save((User) request);
        }
    }

The recommended
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository repository;

    // Method to save a single user
    @PostMapping
    public void saveOne(@RequestBody User user) {
        repository.save(user);
    }

    // Method to save a list of users
    @PostMapping("/list")
    public void saveAll(@RequestBody List<User> users) {
        for (User user : users) {
            repository.save(user);
        }
    }

// rest of the code...

}

At the repository layer:
@Repository
public class UserRepository {

    private List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();

    public UsuarioRepository() {
        users.add(new User("jonh","password"));
        users.add(new User("frank","masterpass"));
    }
    public void save(User user){
        System.out.println("SAVE - Receiving the user at the repository layer");
        System.out.println(user);
        user.add(user);
    }

// rest of the code...
}

I am totally open to correction and advice.
I tried to make a method that would add both a single user to a list or multiple users at once. And it didn't work and I wanted to understand more about why.

An error 500 would leave a stack trace in your log. What error do you see and where in your code?

It starts like this: java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to class pedro.github.io.model.User (java.util.LinkedHashMap is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; pedro.github.io.model.User is in unnamed module of loader 'app'). I just want to make it clear that i am the one causing the problem. In the second way everything works smoothly. My question is about not using a single method to have these two forms of additions in the list. Thanks Federico

The Controller receives a String, so it can't automatically know what to do with it.
I would avoid having an endpoint that behaves in different ways depending on the type of the request body, but if you want, you can do it via parameters or headers.
With parameters:
@PostMapping(value = "/users", params = "list=false")
public ResponseEntity<?> handleUser(@RequestBody User request) {
    repository.save(user);
}

@PostMapping(value = "/users", params = "list=true")
public ResponseEntity<?> handleUserList(@RequestBody List<User> request) {
    for (User user : users) {
        repository.save(user);
    }
}

Or with headers:
@PostMapping(value = "/users", headers = "X-List=false")
public ResponseEntity<?> handleUser(@RequestBody User request) {
    repository.save(user);
}

@PostMapping(value = "/users", headers = "X-List=true")
public ResponseEntity<?> handleUserList(@RequestBody List<User> request) {
    for (User user : users) {
        repository.save(user);
    }
}

